# Is it possible to use `--irreversible-delete` by default for all applicable commands?

Tags: git

It's possible to simplify the display of deleted files in `git diff`, `git show`, etc. by specifying [the `--irreversible-delete` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375227/96588). I can't see a way to configure this as the default in Git 2.43.0, other than hacking together aliases to override all the relevant subcommands to include this flag.

PS: It may not be a good idea to configure this as the default, because `patch` does not recognise the shortened deletion part of the diff. For example, if I try to reproduce a commit:

```
❯ git clone git@gitlab.com:engmark/root.git
❯ cd root
❯ git checkout 42b538814ab0124f16f74cf3dbd0838725e7c57c~1
❯ git show --irreversible-delete 42b538814ab0124f16f74cf3dbd0838725e7c57c | patch -p1
patching file […]
Not deleting file nix/sources.json as content differs from patch
Not deleting file nix/sources.nix as content differs from patch
```

Comment: As the doc says, the resulting patch of this option is not meant for `patch` or `git apply`. No related configuration variable is mentioned, but it has a short equivalent `-D`.